# Homotopy group of exterior powers of simplicial vector spaces

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $C^\bullet$ be a cochain complex in positive degrees, by Dold-Kan correspondence it corresponds to a cosimplicial abelian group $D\colon \Delta\to \mathrm{Ab}$.

Let $F$ be a field, let $C^{\bullet}:=F[-n]$ be the complex concentrated in degree $n$ with $C^n=F$. Let $D$ be its corresponding cosimplicial vector space. Let $\wedge^mD$ be its $m$-th wedge power, which is a simplicial vector space obtained by taking wedge on $D$ functorially.

Is there an explicit calculation for the dimension of the homotopy groups of $\wedge^mD$? Does $\mathrm{dim}\pi_k(\wedge^mD)$ depend only on $n,m,k$, or is also depends on $\mathrm{char}(F)$?

(The original question was asking for explicit expression of cosimplicial Dold-Kan, thank Bertram for the nice description in the comment. But even with this, when $n,k$ goes large, the naive calculation becomes difficult...)

Comment: By abstract nonsense, the inverse Dold-Kan correspondence sends $C^\bullet$ to the cosimplicial abelian group $[n]\mapsto Ch(DK^\bullet(\Delta^n),C^\bullet)$, where $DK^\bullet(\Delta^n)$ is the cellular cochain complex of $\Delta^n$, which forms a simplicial cochain complex since face and degeneracy maps are cellular. Explicitly, $DK^{-1}_n(C)$ is given by families $x_I\in C^{|I|-1}$, where $\emptyset\neq I\subset [n]$, such that $\mathrm d x_I = \sum_{i\notin I} \pm x_{I\sqcup \{i\}}$. In particular, the differential of $C$ is used for $DK^{-1}_n(C)$ (not just the cosimplicial maps).

Comment: Definition 6.22 of arXiv:0908.0116, for instance.

Comment: @BertramArnold Is there a textbook reference for the characterization you mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: @BertramArnold I feel a bit confused, if we are going to calculate the cosimplicial complex of the cochain complex concentrated in degree $n$, in this case, all the codifferentials are zero. By the description above, the cosimplicial complex would have homotopy group every degree..

Answer (score 3):

The analogous question with tensor power instead of exterior power has a simple answer. This gives a simple answer for the exterior power in some cases, including characteristic zero, because if $m!\in F$ is not zero then the $m$th exterior power may be naturally identified with a summand of the $m$th tensor power.

We may view $C^\bullet$ as a model for the cochains of the $n$-sphere $S^n$ relative to a basepoint. Its $m$th tensor power is a model for the cochains of the $m$th smash power of $S^n$, i.e. $S^{mn}$. So the homotopy groups are trivial except for $\pi_{-mn}$, which is $1$-dimensional.

Comment: I believe that the general answer can be expressed as cohomology of the space of unordered configurations of $m$ points in $\mathbb R^n$, twisted by a sign.